# Sending mail via AJAX on localhost, jQuery and javascript differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, email

i'm experimenting with contact form using AJAX. I tried with plain javascript, below is the important part of the code:

```
function sendMail(evt){
        var formdata = new FormData();
        // here I prepare formdata
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open("POST", 'php/mailer.php', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){              
                // do something when succesfull, let's say success()
            } else {
                // do something when not, let's say fail()
            }
        }
        xhr.send(formdata)      
    }   
}
```

So when I work on localhost, when I click 'send' the mail is not sent and fail() is unleashed and when I do it on a server the mail is sent and success() is unleashed. That's cool and understandable for me.

But when I experiment with jQuery and have a code like this:

```
function sendMail(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(myForm).serialize(),
        url: 'php/mailer.php'
    }).done(function(){
        // success()
    }).fail(function(){
        // fail()       
    });
}
```

then on my localhost, when I click 'send', than the mail is not sent, but the success() from done() is unleashed. Why is that and what am I missing?

Comment: `.done()` is not the opposite of `.fail()` - it's what's called when the operation is complete, success or failure. Those are deprecated APIs anyway; `.then()` and `.catch()` are preferred now.

Comment: Ok, but if I see correctly, when I use `then()` and `catch()` it behaves the same way. What should I use in jQuery if I want certain things to happen when a mail is not send although the operation is complete? Should I dig into xhr.readyState and xhr.status?